# Annals of mathematics, why "second series"?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this question should be posted on overflow. So I put it here first.

I see the abbreviation of the journal *Annals of mathematics* is always like *Ann. of Math. (2).* I'm confused why it always comes with "(2)". It probably means "second series". But I never see the first series.

Can someone explain the history or the method of indexing for the annals?

Comment: The meta portion of the site is generally reserved for questions about the main site, MathOverflow, or the underlying Stack Exchange system. I cannot say whether or not this question would be well-received on the main site, but it is off-topic on meta.

Comment: You could instead convert it to a meta question: "would the following question be acceptable on MathOverflow?"

Answer (score 10):

An answer, for the record: the first series of the Annals of Mathematics ran until 1898 volume 12. It then restarted as the second series with 1899 volume 1. You can find the volumes of the first series at [JSTOR.](http://www.jstor.org/journal/annamath) The switch from first to second series coincided with the move of the journal home from the University of Virginia to Harvard. It then moved to its current home in Princeton in 1911, without starting a new series.

[image]